# C library for IRC client

Tags: c, irc

I'm using [libircclient](http://libircclient.sourceforge.net/) for a C project.
Because the lib is not supporting IRC over SSL/TLS I'm searching a different one.
Anyone knows a good C based IRC library?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.ulduzsoft.com/libircclient/ seems pretty nice.

Comment: Not sure why you answered this with a link to the same library

Comment: I don't recall those links heading to the same place back in '12.